# Use a Codename One app for a tv box with tv remote control

Tags: codenameone

I tried to install a Codename One app on a tv box that runs Android 7. It works, except the fact that I cannot use the tv remote control to switch from a Button to another (I need to enable the mouse pointer simulation to tap the Buttons, that is not user friendly).

Any idea to manage this use case? Or the problem is that I'm using a BrowserComponent?

Comment: When you tap select button does something click? If so it's possible that you just don't see the "focus". We support focus behavior and if a key event is sent this should behave correctly. You just need the selected state for components to look distinctive, you can just run any android simulator and use the arrow/enter keys to see how keyboard navigation should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve just published in the Play Store my first Codename One app for Android TV (I hope that it will be approved). I confirm that it can be used with the tv remote control if I do a simple navigabile UI, that can be tested in the Simulator using the arrows. I’ve done tests with an Android TV Box. My problem was that I used a BrowserComponent, that then I replaced with a simple standard UI composed of Buttons.