# Codename One APK Manifest for Android TV

Tags: codenameone

*(Note for the readers: this question is referred only to Codename One)*

As I previously told in [Use a Codename One app for a tv box with tv remote control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445043/use-a-codename-one-app-for-a-tv-box-with-tv-remote-control/54701149#54701149), I published in the Play Store my first Codename One app for Android TV. It works fine with my Android TV-Box, but it was reject.

I received the following e-mail by the Google Play support:

> Thank you for contacting the Android TV Team.
>
> I see that there is some confusion regarding the issues we found in
>   your app.  Your TV APK
>   manifest must contain one of these items:
>
> - Leanback Intent: `<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
>     </intent-filter>`
> - Uses-feature leanback required=true: `<uses-feature
>     android:name="android.software.leanback"android:required="true" />`
> - Uses-feature leanback required=false: `<uses-feature
>     android:name="android.software.leanback"android:required="false" />`
>
> You may also want to refer to the Android TV App Quality page for more
>   information on our review criteria (https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tv-app-quality).
>
> I hope I was able to offer some clarification. Once you have addressed
>   the issues mentioned above, please submit a new version of your app
>   and our team will gladly review it again for you.

So... what do I have to do? Do you have a **build hint** or can you add a build hint for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android.xpermissions` as such:

```
android.xpermissions=<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"android:required="false" />
```

Or `true` if you prefer.

You can also use `android.xintent_filter` to add the intent filter option but if I understand their email correctly it isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you. The technical support of Google didn't tell me all the issues. I read some documentation, so I wrote another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768764/codename-one-apk-manifest-for-android-tv-build-hints