# Codename One APK Manifest for Android TV: build hints

Tags: codenameone

This question is releated to: [Codename One APK Manifest for Android TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756861/codename-one-apk-manifest-for-android-tv)

**I found some documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start**

In this documentation, it's written that `If you do not include the CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER intent filter in your app, it is not visible to users running Google Play on TV devices.`

I tried to use the following two build hints (with include sources):

```
android.xpermissions=<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" /><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

android.xapplication=<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter>
```

This is my generated `AndroidManifest.xml`, that maybe have some issues:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.informaticalibera.apps.unialeph"
      android:versionCode="100"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:minSdkVersion="15"
      android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="27"  />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application  android:label="UniAleph"  android:icon="@drawable/icon"  android:allowBackup="true" >
<provider
          android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
              android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
          </meta-data>
      </provider><meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>        <activity android:name="UniAlephStub"
                  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:label="UniAleph">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter><receiver android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.LocalNotificationPublisher" ></receiver>
<service android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.BackgroundFetchHandler" android:exported="false" />
<activity android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneBackgroundFetchActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
<activity android:name="com.codename1.location.CodenameOneBackgroundLocationActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
<service android:name="com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationHandler" android:exported="false" />
<service android:name="com.codename1.location.GeofenceHandler" android:exported="false" />
<service android:name="com.codename1.media.AudioService" android:exported="false" />    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" /><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" /></manifest>
```

I note that:
`<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter>` should be inside an `<activity>` tag: correct me if I'm wrong. I suppose that the activity should be the same, because there is only one activity. Please note the example at https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start:

```
<application
  android:banner="@drawable/banner" >
  ...
  <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

  </activity>
</application>
```

The second issue is that `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />` is repeated two times: is it a default, so I don't have to specify it?

**Of course I'm not an expert of AndroidManifest.xml, this question is to ask your opinion about these build hints and the generated Manifest before submitting the app again for the review.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify touch screen as it's included by default.

`android.xapplication` is designed for adding additional activities. I think you should have used `android.xintent_filter` for this and not `android.xapplication`.